# Mysql Too many connections: Django sqlAlchemy

Tags: mysql, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy

I have `Django RestFrameWork` application in which we are using `sqlalchemy` library for `MySql` connection.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://username:password@hostaddress/'
                       'DBname', pool_recycle=1800,
                        connect_args={'connect_timeout': 1800}, pool_size=10, max_overflow=10, pool_pre_ping=True)

connection = engine.connect()
```

As the API usage increases the Mysql is creating new connections and count of `threads_connected` keeps growing. After reaching max value it is throwing `Too many connections` error. In `show processList` many process will be in `sleep` mode. If we restart the app all the connections will be reset. The following chart indicates `no.of connections v/s time`. How to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: Since you are not using Django ORM, you'll have to deal with all that on your own. You'll have to use Django's request start/end. However, your question is way to open to really be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You must close connections after you've finished using them because if you don't, the connection stays open until the webserver closes it which might take a lot of time.
The best practice would be using a connection pool. Because opening and closing connections are too heavy and decreases performance. Even if you're using a connection pool you must let the connection go after you've used it.

Comment: I have tried `connection.close()`. But still not resolved. Moreover, we should not close the connection manually instead connection has to close automatically